# If I have a Laravel Sail application, how can I move the dockerized application to an another computer?

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

Is it possible to move the images (mysql, laravel files) with their data as a self contained (or two: mysql and laravel) files, that only needs to start up on the new machine? So moving the docker containers as they are, as they  were developed, and run on another machine?

After reading a lot of tutorials, this step is not clear at all. What I have the docker file, that can be moved of course, but the whole docker-thing makes sense only if I can move the whole application, not only base images. Sorry, I might seem confused a bit, but I really am unfortunately.

Comment: You need `docker-compose.yml`, the 2 docker files for the `services` and maybe some files that belong to those docker files (usually .ini files and things like that). Keep them in the repository or .zip that entire directory. `docker-compose up -d` or `sail up -d` will build those images on that new computer. Since the images aren't on the new computer, `sail up -d` will trigger the build process

Comment: Thanks UnderDog! When you wrote "keep them in the repository", you meant GITHUB repo or local git repo?  If I zip to directory, where the zip file goes? Is it copied the nem machine? Or the zip file contains the docker-compose.yml and the application files too, and together copied to the new machine?

Comment: > the zip file contains the docker-compose.yml and the application files too, and together copied to the new machine  <<<=== that last one, yes, but it's the same as committing it to the github repo: make your changes, commit to github, go to new PC, git clone, `sail up -d` is thr same as .zip on old PC and unzip on new pc, `sail up -d`. On new PC you thrn might have problems with pushing to github. I would still do the git clone thing

Comment: Thanks UnderDog for clarifying. Now I understand it.